# Order SQL Azure Table Columns via SSMS

Tags: sql, azure, ssms

I know you can go into the design view of a table in SQL Server Management Studios and reorder columns as they appear in the design view, however this isn't possible with SQL Azure as the option is disabled. *Is there a way to modify SQL Azure tables so that you can reorder their columns as they appear in the design view?*

I have been running a number of database upgrades over the last few months to support new requirements and would like to reorder the way the columns appear in design view so they're easier to read, i.e. so they start with a primary key, followed by foreign keys, then normal columns and end with the added by, modified by fields. Its purely to make the tables more readable as I manage them over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run a script against the table.  Its a bit of pseudocode but you should get the idea.

```
CREATE TABLE TableWithDesiredOrder(PK,FK1,FK2,COL1,COL2)

INSERT INTO TableWithDesiredOrder(PK,FK1,FK2,COL1,COL2....)
SELECT PK,FK1,FK2,COL1,COL2.... FROM OriginalTable

DROP TABLE OriginalTable
```

Finally Rename the table

```
sp_Rename TableWithDesiredOrder, OriginalTable
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for this but I was hoping a different option would be available, this requires the create-copy-drop steps and also the FK sql to be written. If there is no possible way of doing it then fair enough. I was hoping there might be.

Comment: +1 to David's answer. I don't think there's any other options to reorder the columns. When you reordered the columns through SSMS design view, before clicked save and can have a look on the underlying script the SSMS generated for you by right-click and generate script menu item. You can see the SSMS utilized the same way (create-copy-drop), but it also handles the FK, etc. Maybe you can turn the FK check off before running you script then turn it on.

Comment: Why there is designer support is beyond me. These small limitations are frequent and painful.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option: I use SQL Delta to propagate my db changes from dev db up to Azure db. So in this case, I just change the col order locally using SSMS GUI, and SQL Delta will do the createnew>copytonew>dropold for me, along with my other local changes. (In Project Options, I set Preserve Column Order=Yes.)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same with Azure SQL Database, basically my view changes with ALTER were not taken when did a SELECT * from the view, or the column headers were mixed with the column values.

In order to fix it I dropped the view and re-created it again. That worked.